# Blender Units of scale and solidify modifier

Tags: modifiers, units

I have my units set to metric, centimeters, and unit scale to 1.0, meaning that each grid square ecuals 1 cm.

[image]

My object its about 17 cms long, so it is about 17 grid squares long. I all makes sense until now.

But, when I add the solidify modifier, I set a thickness of 3cm, and the thickness does not look like 3cm at all
[image]

It looks like the solidify modifier thickness is using a different scale for some reason.

What can be happening here? How do I know what thickness I am giving to the model in reality?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scale of your object is all over the place:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Apply the scale with CTRL-A in Object mode and try again.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yL8Ni.jpg

Comment: Not sure what happened to the image there, but the link will show it!

Comment: That is weird, since I scaled it using CTRL-A.

If I set the scales to 1 my model looks really weird.
Thanks for the hint! I did not notice it